# access docker-compose extra_hosts with no port number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, port

I added some extra_hosts in my docker-compose that now looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/.engine-data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp_development
      - POSTGRES_USER=default
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.0-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/.engine-data/redis:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    command: ./wait-for-it.sh redis:6379 -- ./wait-for-it.sh postgres:5432 -- bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/apps/engine
    depends_on:
      - memcached
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    extra_hosts:
     - "my.api:127.0.0.1"
     - "my.webapp:127.0.0.1"
```

My intention is to access web using my.webapp and no localhost:3000. But instead of that, what I get is my web app running at my.webapp:3000

How can I avoid the port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using http, your browser will use a default port of 80 if no number is specified in the URL.

If you want to use a non-standard port, you must specify it in the URL.

For example, if my webserver is running on port 80 on the www.example.com host, I could type http://www.example.com/ into my browser and it is smart enough to connect to port 80.

If I am using a non-standard port (like 3000), then I'd have to type the URL like this: http://www.example.com:3000/

In your case, to not have to specify port 3000 you should update your compose file to publish to your host's port 80 instead of the host's port 3000. Port publishing in docker and docker-compose take the format of :. This means you'd need to switch from `3000:3000` to `80:3000` in your compose file and rerun `docker-compose up -d`.

You also mentioned wanting to access your service using the "my.webapp" hostname instead of the "localhost" hostname. You can achieve this by adding a hosts file entry on your machine so that "my.webapp" resolves to 127.0.0.1. You could also use any other number of DNS name resolution methods to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I don't need to edit hosts file because that's exactely what docker-compose's extra_hosts does (in the host inside the docker container). But you are very right on the port. Thanks!

Comment: just be aware that extra_hosts won't make any changes to what is resolvable in the host-- only what is resolvable inside the container.

Comment: But i'm running the app inside a container. That means everything going on there will match the configuration in extra_hosts. Doesn't it @programmerq ?

Comment: then the port that you publish to the host probably doesn't matter. If you're not accessing the containerized app from the outside at all, then just skip publishing the port. You'd need to also update your containerized app to listen on port 80 directly instead of 3000.